# Using a WCF service to share information across clients

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to develop a system to share information across 2 windows applications with different update loops.

I developed a solution that uses a WCF service to store and retrieve data. However this data is different across clients and therefore showing different values for each applications.

The service I tried to implement are similar to this

```
namespace TEST_Service_ServiceLibrary
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface TEST_ServiceInterface
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData();

        [OperationContract]
        void StoreData(string data);
   }
}

namespace TEST_Service_ServiceLibrary
{
    // Core service of the application, stores and provides data: 
    public class TEST_Service : TEST_ServiceInterface
    {
        string TEST_string;

        // Used to pull stored data
        public string GetData()
        {
              return TEST_string;
        }

        // Used to store data
        public void StoreData(string data)
        {
            TEST_string = data;
        }
    }
}
```

Each of the applications creates a TEST_Service client.

I tested the `GetData` and `StoreData` functions and they work fine independently, however when I use `StoreData` on one application and test the `GetData` method from the other the data appears to be empty.

I have looked around but haven't found a solution to this problem, is there a work around for this? or should I change my approach? I thought of using a local data base but I'm not sure this is the best way to solve it

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm wondering why you mention WCF *services*, plural. If you have one service that stores data and retrieves it, then any number of clients could use it to store data and clients could also retrieve what was stored. Is that what you're doing, or do you have multiple WCF services? Also, where is the data stored?

Comment: Are you sure that there is only one instance of TEST_Service?

Comment: Yes I only have one service, I'll edit the mentions to be clear

Comment: As for the instance, I am in fact only running the service once and connecting to it from two clients.

Comment: Data is stored in the TEST_string internal variable of the TEST_Service class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one instance of your service class. If you want to have your data in memory, you will need to run it in single instance mode:

`[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]`

Now keeping your data in memory might not be the best option anyway. You should look for a data store of some kind and then make *that* store a persistent instance with a single interface. Then it does not matter how many of your service instances are used.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This did solve the issue. I'll keep trying to find alternatives, but at least now I can keep testing

Answer (score 0):

If your WCF service was storing information in a database, then information stored on one request would go to the database, and when another request retrieved it, the result would come from that database. So if one client stored something, another could retrieve it.

The reason why this isn't working is because in response to each request your application is creating a new instance of the `TEST_Service` class. That means `TEST_string`, where you are storing values between requests, is a new `string`. It doesn't contain the previous value.

For experimentation you could try changing the string to `static`:

```
static string TEST_string;
```

...and then the value would persist between instances of the service class. But that still wouldn't be effective because your WCF service could be deployed to multiple servers, and then each one would have a separate instance of the class. Updating one wouldn't update the others. Or, if the service application restarted then the value would be lost. (From the context I assume that you're just experimenting with this.)

So ultimately you'd want some way to persist data that wouldn't depend on any of those factors, but would "survive" even when the instance of the service class goes out of scope or the application shuts down.